# Disable horizontal scroll in UITextView (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, horizontal-scrolling

I've been trying to figure out how to disable horizontal scrolling in a UITextView (I've seen many questions about this, but none of them have helped me). The scrolling issue occurs when I rotate the textview. The code used for this is here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 10) // prevent that text near right edge it cut away
        textView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, 300)
        self.textView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2 * 3.14159 / 180.0)  
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 // check that textview stays within view
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I have tried to disable the horizontal scrolling by setting `textView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, 300)` as suggested in another stackoverflow question, but it doesn't have any effect. I've also tried to remove the inset, but it didn't lock the horizontal scrolling either.

I need to be able to scroll vertically, so to disable scrolling entirely is not an option. I'm using Xcode 6 with iOS 8 as deployment target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to to set the content size to the actual size, and do it a little later in the process, in viewDidAppear.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  self.textView.contentSize = self.textView.bounds.size;
}
```

Comment: It do work. However if i'm using a long `NSAttributedString` in `textView.attributedText`, then when I scroll half-way down, the remaining text disappears (see [this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oef119v2f9qf80n/Skærmbillede%202014-10-04%2002.22.21.png?dl=0)) and I have to tap a couple of times before it appears. I've read that it can be solved by changing `textView.scrollEnabled` to false before setting the `textView.attributedText` and then to true afterwards, but that causes the textView to be scrollable even if I only have a couple of words in it.

Answer (score 1):

What about  `textView.scrollEnabled = NO;`? It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In swift:

textView.scrollEnabled = false